# git push -u origin master is redirecting to Authorize Git Credential Manager

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I am new to git hub and I am learning how to use it. Currently I am at my git bash terminal and I want to push some files into a repository just to check how things work. So I followed some steps as guided in a youtube video and I did get result for most of the commands. But when I write this command `git push -u origin master` , I am constantly redirected to a window which is Authorize Git Credential Manager. I have generated SSH keys for authentication purpose for the first time. But I don't seem to grasp the of concept how to use them I suppose.

At present I don't want to give permission to Authorize Git Credential Manager , so I want suggestions regarding how to authenticate using SSH keys.

The link to the Authorize Git Credential Manager page is given for better understanding.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v9VL.png

Comment: origin  https://github.com/Partha_98/Repo-to-learn-git-.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/Partha_98/Repo-to-learn-git-.git (push)

Comment: When I did  git remote -v , I get 
origin  git@github.com:Partha_98/Repo-to-learn-git-.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Partha_98/Repo-to-learn-git-.git (push)

Comment: When I did git push -u origin master
I get this response
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

Comment: Yeah, few minutes back I wrote this command git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Partha_98/Repo-to-learn-git-.git
after that I did git remote -v  and git push -u origin master and I get this response ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Comment: Ok let my try it and If it don't work, I will get back to you here

Comment: I am overwhelmed by the content and the resources of that discussion. I am a beginner so I don't know how to proceed, like there are many ways people have solved the issue. But as a beginner, I just don't want to try different solutions without understanding them. Like making a change at present without knowing the other side of it .

Comment: At present when I did  git push origin master , I was not redirected to Authorize Git Credential Manager surprisingly.  Rather I get this response 
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.